# Differences in singleton declarations

Tags: javascript, singleton, declaration

I am having a hard time understanding what the difference in the following singleton declarations is:

```
var Database = {
    hostname : "db1",
    opendatabase : function() {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

and

```
var Database = (function () {
    var hostname = "db1";

    return {
        opendatabase : function () {
            //some code here
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: The second one is not valid JavaScript as it contains syntax errors.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Ok i fixed the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment the second code sample is not valid. This is because of the outer most curly brackets. The correct way of doing it would be this:

```
var Database = (function() {
    var hostname = "db1";

    return {
        opendatabase : function() {
            //some code here
        }
    };
})();
```

That being said there is one main difference between the two code samples. In the first one `hostname` is a property on the object, meaning the following would be valid code:

```
console.log(Database.hostname); //outputs "db1"
```

In the second sample `hostname` is a private variable, meaning it can not be accessed outside the Database constructor function:

```
console.log(Database.hostname); //outputs undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

First, a small syntax correction.
The second snippet should be

```
var Database = (function () {
    var hostname = "db1";

    return {
        opendatabase : function () {
            //some code here
        }
    }
}());
```

The difference between these two Singletons is, that in the first one, everybody can change the `hostname` with `Database.hostname = 'I changed your stuff';`, but in the second one, only the functions of `Database` can access `hostname` because it was declared in an anonymous function.

Comment: Great. In the second singleton, is the function being returned always the same, or is it a different instance every time?

Comment: in the second singleton, the function containing `hostname` is only called once, and the `opendatabase` function is also created once. no multiple instances. Just one instance with private variables